# "travel at very high speeds" / "travel at very high speed"

Tags: sentence-construction

> These trains are fast. They can travel **at very high speeds**.
>
> These trains are fast. They can travel **at very high speed**.

Can I say "at very high speed" in that context? If it is possible, what's the difference between two sentences?

*[I can say the first version in my native language, but it's very, very informal.]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say Eurostar can travel at 179, 180 or 190 miles per hour. It can travel at very high speeds. Right now it goes 160mph, which is still a very high speed.

“High speed” for the general case is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

In English, both are possible. I slightly prefer the second but there isn't much difference. Neither is notably informal.